# Is Meteor Compatible With the Latest release of MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Is Meteor 1.0.3.2 compatible with MongoDB Version 3.0.0 or 2.6.8? I am using a replica set and plan to host on a service such as Compose.io, which supports the newer versions of MongoDB. I cannot find anywhere the latest compatible version, nor am I aware the version of Mongo that Meteor ships with out of the box. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meteor just uses a self version of MongoDB for "development" purposes. In production deployment you generally ( basically always ) use an external server for the database store. And one of a version likely greater than the last packaged deployment for meteor.

So don't be hung up on "which version" is in your meteor installation. Though you probably should be concerned with at least getting hold of a a possible deployment target version of MongoDB and testing somewhere before you release into the real wide world.

That said, and not wanting to detract from proper testing procedures that you "should" have in place. The versions of MongoDB at least since 2.2 through to 3.0 ( current, as of writing ) all share a consistent basic API from the driver perspective of the code that you should be implementing. There is little difference with the main exception that new interfaces were introduced in MongoDB 2.6, but of course these remain valid for MongoDB 3.0 as well.

The general rule is if you are really worried then consult your API documentation for "DEPRECATED" notices. That is generally what tells you if methods you are using are soon to disappear and that you should be using something else.

Bottom line here is that generally speaking, just because a server product increases in version does not mean there is a breaking API for client services. If that actually happens anywhere, then I would say the vendor got it wrong. But that is not the case with MongoDB.

Just use it. There might be some MongoDB 3.0 features that cannot be used because they are not supported in the driver version in your current release of Meteor. But that is the most common case to happen, and the complete opposite of the question you asked.